# How to use Alias pattern with ElasticSearch in Grafana?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I using ElascticSearch as Source. On my table i have two metrics and a groupBy, and i would like to change the name of metrics+ groupBy on table:
[image]

But this doesn't work for me. I also checked this: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4697

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jan this is a table so patterns don't work on table.

I solved it from Visualization section:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use two queries instead of one and define alias per query:
Older Grafana < 6:
[image]

Current Grafana > 6:
[image]

See also help for `alias patterns`:
[image]